# Why does my AS3 DataGrid with sortable columns show wrong movieclip loaded in to cell after sorting?

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid, cellrenderer, flash-cs6

I have a datagrid component in my AS3 project and have a custom cell renderer assigned to one column that loads a movie clip into a cell depending on the value of that cell data. For example if the cell data is the number 1 I load movieclip1, if 2 i load movieclip2. This works great. In the CustomCellRenderer Class I use the

```
 public function set data(value:Object):void {
   _data = value;
   // value.Number is the value that I use to determine which movie clip to show in this cell 
   source = "movie"+value.Number;
 }
```

When the DataGrid loads, the correct movie clip is loaded in to the cell. However when a user sorts the columns by clicking on the header of the column some of the movieclips dont load. I have checked that the data is sorting fine, and when I trace out "movie"+value.Number the correct string is displayed.

I think that maybe I need to unload the movie clips in each cell before setting source again? How do I do this?

Another thing I have noticed is that when the DataGrid needs to scroll because there are more rows than fit on the screen (duh!) then only one set of movieclips will be displayed at once, as if there is an 'active' or 'in focus' cell in which the only movie clips will display. Again, I am guessing that Flash is trying to only show the movie clips that are in the visible portion of the scrollable DataGrid and trying to refresh each time I scroll. However only 1 cell shows movie clips rather than all of the visible portion (which is about 8 rows).

thanks

Comment: it may be possible that the set data is not called all the times because of the rendering mechanism. I suggest you try to call an dg.invalidateList() after the sort is complete. Or (but this is not nice) move your logic also to updateDisplayList() in the renderer.

Comment: At least the "updateDisplayList" thing will help you check if this is only a rendering issue and not a logic/sorting problem. I do not suggest this as a permanent solution for performance reasons. Also are you overriding "commitProperties" in your renderer ???

Comment: Hi thanks for your replies, I have not been able to look at this until now. As far as I know - no I am not overriding commitProperties. I have tried your suggestion to call dg.invalidateList() to try and refresh the list. I am now more concerned with the problem that the movieclips disappear when the list is scrolled rather than sorting as i have now removed the sorting functionality. So as a quick check I am calling invalidateList() periodically and can confirm that setData() is called each time, however the list still does not show all the movieclips I expect to see in the all the cells...??

Comment: Since your "source" is actually set correctly, the troublesome code should be the one that handles source's assignment, I expect this to be a setter function, otherwise the source should not automatically update anything. Do you mind sharing the source setter code?

Comment: Thanks for your response.. well the above code is the source setter code in the custom CellRenderer class that i have created. The source that gets assigned is the "movie"+value.number part which is a movieclip in the library - which is going to be either 1,2 or 3 so have those movie clip symbols in my library (movie1, movie2, movie3). Im not sure what code other than the above you are asking me to share. The public function set data() code is the only code in the cell renderer that i have changed from the default class. When i set up the datagrid I use column.cellRenderer= MyCellRenderer;

Comment: I was thinking that setting source is actually more than setting some variable, like if there is a setter property for source, with `public function set source(value:String):void` somewhere else. Google says there is such thing as source property, though, but it is in inherited code. I don't have experience with fl.* components at all, so those words come from pure logic. Maybe you could try invoking `invalidate()` method after assigning source?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it has something to do with datagrid cell virtualization as it tries to optimize scroll performance and recycles cell layouts. Try to set virtual layout to false, maybe it helps.